# SQL Select only rows with Minimum Value on a Column with Where Condition

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Table:

```
| id | productId | orderIndex | rejected |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |  1        |   0        |   1      |
| 2  |  1        |   1        |   0      |
| 3  |  1        |   2        |   0      |
| 4  |  2        |   0        |   0      |
| 5  |  2        |   1        |   1      |
| 6  |  3        |   0        |   0      |
```

How can I select one row per productId with minimum orderIndex that not rejected?

Expected result:

```
| id | productId | orderIndex | rejected |
------------------------------------------
| 2  |  1        |   1        |   0      |
| 4  |  2        |   0        |   0      |
| 6  |  3        |   0        |   0      |
```

I tried this query, but don't recieved correct result:

```
SELECT id, productId, min(orderIndex)
FROM table
WHERE rejected = 0
GROUP BY productId
```

This one don't work also:

```
SELECT id, productId, min(orderIndex)
FROM (
    SELECT id, productId, orderIndex
    FROM table
    WHERE rejected = 0
) t
GROUP BY productId
```

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Also, your title says max value, but everything in your question suggests you meant minimum. Once you know which you need, please edit the title or question accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start by selecting the minimum orderIndex of products that are not rejected like this:

```
SELECT productId, MIN(orderIndex)
FROM myTable
WHERE rejected = 0
GROUP BY productId;
```

Once you have that, you can join it with your original table on the condition that productId and minOrderIndex match:

```
SELECT m.id, m.productId, m.orderIndex
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT productId, MIN(orderIndex) AS minOrderIndex
  FROM myTable
  WHERE rejected = 0
  GROUP BY productId) tmp ON tmp.productId = m.productId AND tmp.minOrderIndex = m.orderIndex;
```

My query makes the assumption that there are no duplicate (productId, orderIndex) pairs. As long as those don't exist, this will work just fine. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243f9/2) example.

Comment: Not sure if I remember correctly. When you just `JOIN` MySQL interprets that as `LEFT JOIN` which is not what we need here. I would suggest to use`INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: No, join by itself is interpreted as an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0196f/2

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT productId, min(orderIndex) minIdx
FROM table1
WHERE rejected = 0
GROUP BY productId
  ) t1
ON t.productId = t1.productId
  AND t.orderIndex = t1.minIdx;
```